# ruby on rails int to minutes::seconds::milliseconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line, which shows the minutes and seconds. But I have to add milliseconds to it as well for greater accuracy. How do I add that in this line, or is there an easier way to get the desired result?

```
@duration = [cd.ExactDuration/60000000, cd.ExactDuration/1000000 % 60].map{|t| t.to_s.rjust(2, '0') }.join(':'))
```

The exact duration type is saved in microseconds. So the first converts to microseconds to minutes, the second part is microseconds to seconds. Now I need to add milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd.ExactDuration/1000 % 1000` should do the trick.

Of course you may also want to tweak the formatting, since that's a datum you don't want to right-justify in a 2-wide field;-). I'd suggest [sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/function.html#sprintf) for string-formatting, though I realize its use is not really intuitive unless you come from a C background.

Comment: That works, is there a way to just make it precise to the last 2 digits though.

For example, my last answer 00:03:109
I would want 00:03:11

Comment: Of course -- then you *DON'T* want milliseconds as you said, but rather centiseconds (hundredths of a second) -- and then you don't need to tweak your formatting;-). `((cd.ExactDuration+5000)/10000) % 100` will do it, including the rounding you now imply.

Comment: @Ryan, if the answer solves your problem, accept it: that's THE basic bit of stack overflow etiquette!